# PostGIS & QGIS: Select Object/ID for foreign key from mapped points?

Tags: qgis, postgis

Is there a way, when working with QGIS connected to PostGIS, to have foreign key fields in the form allow selecting the value (primary key from another table) by selecting the object from the other table off the map?

If that is possible, is it further possible to use a custom SQL query to give you what should be plotted on the map for the user to select from. (Obviously, there would need to be a way to mark the result columns of said query with one being the primary/foreign key value to put in the field if the user selects that row. And it would also obviously need a point/geometry/geography column.)

I ask because I have some objects (let's call them A) that have foreign keys to objects that have no geometry of their own (let's call them B), but are related to objects that do have geometry (let's call them C). So I would like to fill A's foreign key column with B.id by selecting B off the map, having plotted B on the map with geometry from the related C objects.